# jQuery Datatable button in row with variable from ajax source

Tags: jquery, datatables

I'm trying to add a button in a datatable row with the following code:

```
$("#tbllandinfo").DataTable({
            searching: false,
            ordering: false,
            paging: false,
            bInfo: false,   
            ajax: {
                url: '/land_and_crops/id/' + $("#eid").val(),
                dataSrc: '', 
            },
            columns: [
                { data: 'ldacres' },            
                { data: 'ldyields' },           
                { data: 'cname' },
            { 
                sortable:false,
                defaultContent:  "<button class='btn btn-danger btn-delete form-control pull-right' dbcolid='ldid' dbcolidval= dbtable='land_det'>X</button>",
            }
        ]
    });
```

The button displays but the problem I'm facing is that I need to put the value of `ldid`, that comes from ajax JSON into the dbcolidval attribute in the button.

Every row button will have its own value.

Sample data:

```
 {"ldid":4,"ldentity":7,"ldacres":"5.00","ldyields":2,"ldcrop":5,"cname":"RICE"},

 {"ldid":7,"ldentity":7,"ldacres":"10.00","ldyields":1,"ldcrop":6,"cname":"MAIZE",

 {"ldid":6,"ldentity":7,"ldacres":"4.00","ldyields":1,"ldcrop":3,"cname":"CORN"}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use render instead of defaultContent. See discussed here: (https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/23649/how-do-i-access-columns-data-inside-of-defaultcontent)